# LogicApps on VS2019 says "The term 'Get-AzureRmResourceGroup' is not recognized"

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure-logic-apps

How to fix my problem without removing Az?

I have removed RM and installed Az.
I have LogicApps on VS2019 (16.6.5) and trying to deploy.

I get error:

```
"The term 'Get-AzureRmResourceGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file..."
```

I next tried to re-install RM by PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module AzureRM

```
ackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this syste
m:'Login-AzAccount,Logout-AzAccount,Resolve-Error,Send-Feedback'. This module 'AzureRM.profile
' may override the existing commands. If you still want to install this module 'AzureRM.profil
e', use -AllowClobber parameter.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPac 
kage) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandAlreadyAvailable,Validate-ModuleCommandAlreadyAvailable, 
Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Comment: Do you mean you use powershell to deploy the logic app? Why not use the [`Publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio#publish-logic-app-updates) button?

Comment: It seem like RM is missing for VS

Answer (score 2):

Az and AzureRM cannot be imported side-by-side into the same PowerShell session. If you do not want to migrate your scripts from AzureRM to Az right away, there are two main options:

Install Az in PowerShell Core, and leave AzureRM in Windows PowerShell
Install Az and AzureRM side-by-side in Windows PowerShell and ensure scripts do not mix the modules

Details steps are documented [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/documentation/announcing-az-module.md#installing-az-and-azurerm-side-by-side)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az